# JQuery UI Tabs Content not loaded inside the generated content divs?

Tags: jquery-ui-tabs

Here's my code:

```
<div class="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">tab2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">tab3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-4">tab4</a></li>
</ul>
   <div id="tabs-1">
      tab1
   </div>
   <div id="tabs-2">
      tab2
  </div>
   <div id="tabs-3">
      tab3
   </div>
   <div id="tabs-4">
      tab4
   </div>
</div>
<script>$(function() { $( ".tabs" ).tabs(); });</script>
```

The tab titles are fine however the content is not displayed properly, here's a screenshot
[image]

When I viewed firebug's code, I found that the content tabs are loaded but the content is not included in them. How to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your script tag:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

It looks like you are trying to use the class selector with yours script.